# Rendering CircleImage Problems

Tags: android, android-imageview

> Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.  The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.example.ars.orbit.ui.CircleImage (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>   Tip: Try to build the project.

CircleImage layout

```
<com.example.ars.orbit.ui.CircleImage
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lingkar"
    android:src="@drawable/lingkaran"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>
```

**CircleImage**

```
public class CircleImage extends ImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;
    private boolean mDisableCircularTransformation;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);    
        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You do realize there are several libraries for Circle ImageViews, yes? https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView